# How to find differences of sentences using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to find differences of sentences.

For example thwo sentences.

> "this is my book" and "this is may book"

I want to find the difference of "my" and "may"

or

> "how are this cook" and "hope and this cook"

I want to learn word or letter differences.

Comment: Any diff is simple as long as not elements are missing on one side. When that can happen things get really difficult.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? Can you share the code you have written to solve this problem? And also explain the issue you are facing?

Comment: Can you clarify the output you’re after? Do you want the absolute differences or would you accept a percentage comparison value that is derived via an algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the following code:

```
        string s1 = "this is my book";
        string s2 = "this is may book";
        var result = s1.Split(' ').Except(s2.Split(' '));

        Console.WriteLine("difference words is: "+string.Join(" , ", result)); 
       // result==> difference words is: my
```

or

```
        string s3 = "how are this cook";
        string s4 = "hope and this cook";
        var resul2 = s3.Split(' ').Except(s4.Split(' ')).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("difference words is: " + string.Join(" , ", resul2))
       //result==> difference words is: how , are
```